# HTML Website Not Loading on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

This website:

http://lastergroup.com/epe/epe19-240/dev/index.html

is loading well on all browsers (Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Edge), except on Internet Explorer (IE) 11, can someone please help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this article will help you diagnose the issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/cannot-access-websites

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/ie-11-doesnt-preload-while-preloading-with-500/e5d8611d-1a6f-4d2d-beba-4cbb214bd99e

Also keep in mind that the site **is not secure**, and you may have to fix that or change the permissions in IE 11:

https://www.support.com/how-to/how-to-fix-site-is-not-secure-in-internet-explorer-12900

Edit: I also noticed that the back-to-top link is not doing its job.

Comment: Not the problem. I found that when I remove the "class="preload"" from the div at the beginning of page (second div after the body), the page loads, but not entirely. But thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: This may help:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/ie-11-doesnt-preload-while-preloading-with-500/e5d8611d-1a6f-4d2d-beba-4cbb214bd99e

Comment: It was not helpful, but thank you for the recommendation. Like I said, the issue is the "preload" class, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You could possibly ask another question being more specific about IE 11 and the preload class. I'm sure you could get more help